# Firefox Web Developer Tools - Hide Extra Console

Tags: firefox

How do I hide / remove the extra console in the Firefox Web Developer tools? It's wasting space and there isn't a close button or context menu to get rid of it.

[image: Firefox Extra Console]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Keyboard_shortcuts:

> Toggle split console (except if console is the currently selected
>   tool)

Press the `Escape` key to toggle the extra console in Firefox; the developer tools *must* have focus for this to work though.

Comment: Thanks. The split console is so annoying on a smaller screen, and the “hide split console” button mentioned [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/Split_console) does not exist.

Comment: @SimonA.Eugster Glad to post something helpful! I have many keys elegantly binded (without breaking any native functionality) and I close all modals and collapse drop-down menus with the Escape key. I know others who try to add some extra details do the same on their systems. I always try to make sure I can find the answer I need later on by posting it in a specific a fashion. I wonder, long after we're gone, how much of an impact our work will have? :-)